# Hive query for a specific scenario

Tags: java, sql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Suppose my data is like below:

[image]

And the output should be as below:

[image]

The Conditions are:

1. If the `cnsm_id` consists `Type_cd='P'` then I need only that tuple
2. If the `cnsm_id` with has either `type_cd=P` or `type_cd=A` then the record should have `max(timestamp)`.
3. If the `cnsm_id` doesn't have the `type_cd='P'` then it should take the `type_cd='A'` record with the largest timestamp

Please who knew the answer could help me in solving this query?

Comment: Have you done *anything* to try to solve this problem on your own?  Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CNSM_ID,
    MAX(t),
    TYPE_CD
FROM(
SELECT
    CNSM_ID,
    MAX(TIMESTAMP) AS t, 
    type
FROM
    TBL_NAME
GROUP BY
    CNSM_ID,
    TYPE_CD
ORDER BY t DESC) AS TBL_NAME1
GROUP BY CNSM_ID;
```